# Using explode multiple time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say my origninal data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col_1': np.arange(4), 
'col_2': [['ab', 'bc'], 
          ['bc', 'be'], 
          ['ca', 'de', 'af'], 
          ['acd', 'afg', 'a']
         ]})
```

Then I use explode to unstack `col_2`:

```
df = df.explode('col_2')
```

Now I apply another function that again produces a list as result. For the sake of simplicity let's just use  `list`. So we run:

```
df['col_3'] = df.col_2.apply(list)
```

Now we'd like to explode again, so I can again run properly vectorized functions on it. But if I apply explode again several duplicated entries will be created. I suspect this to have something to do with the duplicated indices.

**edit:** I've meanwhile confiremed that if I i create a new Index column, no duplicates will be produced. So my main problem is solved. But is there a way to for example create a MultiIndex when using explode?

Full code to quickly ilustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from IPython.display import display
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': np.arange(4), 'col_2': [['ab', 'bc'], ['bc', 'be'], ['ca', 'de', 'af'], ['acd', 'afg', 'a']]})
df = df.explode('col_2')
df['col_3'] = df.col_2.apply(list)

df_tmp = df.explode('col_3')
display(df.loc[0])
display(df_tmp.loc[0])
```

**Edit: Desired Output for index 0:**

```
| index | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| 0 | 0 | ab | a |
| 0 | 0 | ab | b |
| 0 | 0 | bc | b |
| 0 | 0 | bc | c |
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Added. I'm sorry I couldn't get a properly formated markdown table.

Comment: are you looking for: df_tmp.set_index(['col_1', 'col_2']) ?

Comment: this is all going to be about indexes.   after an `explode()` you will notice duplicates in index.  `reset_index()` on first explode before second explode would be my recommendation